# In multi-class, is the average accuracy of each class in confusion metrics equal to the accuracy calculated from cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

When I calculate accuracy through cross validation, it gives me a different accuracy than when I calculate through confusion metrics. Why does it give different accuracy? Is overall calculated accuracy through cross validation or accuracy-matrix not equal to the average accuracy of each class in confusion matrix?

For example, I obtain accuracy by using cross validation is 85% and the average accuracy of each class in confusion metrics is 95%. Why the huge difference in both measures?

Comment: Accuracy from which confusion matrix?

Comment: multiclass confusion matrix